# Get og:image url with PHP

Tags: php, share-open-graph

I'm trying to adapt some PHP code I found here to make it get the og:image url from any url,
The tags are usally like so (and i will make a isset for when one is not present)

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://MYGREATOTHERDOMAIN.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

or could be

```
<meta name="og:image" content="https://images.MYGREATDOMAIN.co.uk/img.jpg"/>
```

The code I'm using..

```
$htmlContent = file_get_contents($singlemeal[0][link]);

// read all og:image tags into an array
preg_match_all('/<meta[^>]+>/i',$htmlContent, $imgTags); 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($imgTags[0]); $i++) {
  // get the source string
  preg_match('/type=og:image',$imgTags[0][$i], $imgage);
  preg_match('/content="([^"]+)/i',$imgTags[0][$i], $imgage);

  // remove opening 'content=' tag, can`t get the regex right
  $origImageSrc[] = str_ireplace( 'content="', '',  $imgage[0]);
}
// will output all your img src's within the html string
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($origImageSrc);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is now pulling all the 'content' found in all meta tags and I need it to only search for and return og:image url, but not sure how to make it do this, any help greatly appreciated.

Edit to add: I probably don't need an array since I will only be returning 1 output url, I simply started with the example code thinking it be a good place to start and adapt to suit but have got stuck. Thanks again.

If we run the above on say https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/classic-sausage-mash the output im getting is..

```
Array
(
    [0] => width=device-width
    [1] => 
    [2] => Classic sausage & mash recipe - BBC Good Food
    [3] => A classic family comfort food meal with creamy mash and golden brown sausages. Fresh seasonal veg like steamed broccoli make this meal 3 of your 5 a day
    [4] => https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/classic-sausage-mash
    [5] => Classic sausage & mash
    [6] => BBC Good Food
    [7] => A classic family comfort food meal with creamy mash and golden brown sausages. Fresh seasonal veg like steamed broccoli make this meal 3 of your 5 a day
    [8] => article
    [9] => https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/sausage-and-mash-2cb0bee.jpg
    [10] => Classic sausage & mash
    [11] => 400
    [12] => 440
    [13] => summary_large_image
    [14] => BBC Good Food
    [15] => @bbcgoodfood
    [16] => Hkgeqt1fifrCaIrdMvoMK4wxVtQsqQPh3VY77hxXjWg
    [17] => e0dc3ea18b52d6be8f7d588b29af3605
    [18] => 31296838546
    [19] => 37
)
```

Comment: What is the output now?

Comment: Use `preg_match('/content="([^"]+)/i',$str, $matches);` and then you can access the url through `$matches[1]` if there is one.

Comment: @RobinGillitzer I've added this to the OP

Comment: @CodeSpirit would you please put this into my code as an answer?

Comment: @GlenKeybit I just copied it from your code and changed the variable names. You should do proper debugging then you would find out that your code already works. Just access `$imgage[1]`